# Managing data created with an API in multiple environments

Tags: database

I have a staging and production environment for my application and store `Stripe::Customer` ids in my database. Occasionally, I want to copy production data to my staging database, but the `Stripe::Customer` ids no longer work because they were originally created using the live `Stripe` API key and my staging server is configured to use the test API key.

Is there a best practice for migrating data between environments that have different API keys?

Comment: Dealing with a similar problem. Were you ever able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

My first pass on solving this would be to use a forward error recovery pattern. If the app detects it is running the staging environment, allow failed lookups to query the production environment for the record, and then recreate that state in the test environment, update your staging db with the new record id, and return the newly created record.